# curl error 51 - of multiple requesting machines, only one has the issue

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, curl

I have an SSL cURL request that fails from a single machine with the following error:

```
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

This error seems to have popped up overnight, and isolated to a single machine.  The request was working, then the machine was shutdown.  Today, the machine was powered up and the request no longer works.

Details:

- Machine is running linux 3.12.28
- Multiple other machines have no problem with the same request,
  all on the same network.
- The network of the machine in question seems to be fine otherwise

Things tried:

- Setting the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf to 8.8.8.8
- Power cycling
- Disabled all but one network interface

Has anyone had this problem before?  What did you do to fix it? Any ideas for further debugging? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the time of the machine? The correct time (more or less) is necessary to validate the certificates.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I just checked, and the time is correct.

Comment: Try using `curl -v` or `curl --trace -` (followed by the rest of the curl arguments) on the problem machine and a working one and add the results to your question.

Comment: Great!  Thank you.  I will try that and report back with my results.